# How long are text messages saved in the iCloud server?

Tags: icloud, messages, macos

..and how can I get rid of them before they are subpoenaed?

Comment: I would ask a lawyer.

Answer (score 1):

As of the last update of Apple's [iOS Security Guide](https://www.apple.com/business/docs/iOS_Security_Guide.pdf), May 2016:

> iMessage messages are queued for delivery to offline devices. Messages are currently stored for *up to 30 days*.

(emphasis mine)

Note this time period has increased from a prior version of this guide, which stated that messages were queued for up to seven days.

If, by "text message", you actually mean SMS messages, those do not cross onto Apple's servers at all unless you have SMS Forwarding enabled, to have messages from your iPhone forwarded to other devices such as a Mac or iPad. Forwarded SMS messages are encrypted in the same method as iMessage messages (elaborated in the guide). It appears that the 30-day timeframe also applies to forwarded SMS messages.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear how long the messages are stored after transmission through iMessage. But there are plenty of places to find the messages if truly needed. For example, in any iPhone backups, iCloud or local hard drive from iTunes backups: Both not-deleted messages (at the time the backup was taken) and many DELETED messages are available in the backups. I work on the program [Decipher TextMessage which allows you to view these messages from the backups](http://deciphertools.com), and we've helped many people recover messages needed for court cases.

Answer (score 0):

iCloud makes multiple backups of your iOS devices over time, some of these backups are available to restore and some are not. Also you need to be clear on messages that have been deleted and messages that still exist, as both are still in the iCloud database.

To delete all data you would need to wipe the iOS device (there are many options on the market), wipe any iTunes backups on your PC/Mac and delete the iCloud backups of all devices that had that iMessage.

Even then, you might not delete all the copies if they were intercepted while they were delivered or backed up to a location you cannot purge or control.